# Deployment fails with SI4T and SDL Tridion 2013, nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/DTDEntityResolver

Tags: 2013, si4t

Trying to setup [SI4T](http://si4t.github.io/) on SDL Tridion 2013 for the first time, I've used the [BitNami Apache Solr installer](http://bitnami.com/stack/solr/installer) to get Solr 4.4.0 on my system and setup a core for my staging website on that.

Next I followed the [SI4T Quickstart guide](https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/wiki/Quickstart-Guide) to add the TBBs and configure the Deployer (copied all the jars and added the config bits). That seems to all be correct, but when publishing a Page, Deployment fails and the following error shows up in the `cd_core.log`:

```
2013-10-02 13:15:30,404 ERROR StorageManagerFactory - Fatal error, unable to load the StorageManagerFactory
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlserverEntityManagerFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/DTDEntityResolver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1093) ~[spring-context.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory.configureBundle(JPADAOFactory.java:66) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.configureStorage(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:91) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.configureStorage(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:65) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.configure(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:51) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.configuration.step.ConfigurationStepLoader.configure(ConfigurationStepLoader.java:47) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.configure(StorageManagerFactory.java:137) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.services.BaseService.<init>(BaseService.java:107) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.<init>(StorageManagerFactory.java:104) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.reloadInstance(StorageManagerFactory.java:84) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.<clinit>(StorageManagerFactory.java:56) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.deploy.PageHandler.deploy(PageHandler.java:58) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:90) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy.processPage(PageDeploy.java:145) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy.processItem(PageDeploy.java:118) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:83) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:87) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.process(SectionVisitor.java:60) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.Processor.process(Processor.java:109) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.workers.ProcessorWorker.doWork(ProcessorWorker.java:77) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.ProcessingPhase.execute(ProcessingPhase.java:72) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:186) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:97) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:61) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:82) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:175) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/DTDEntityResolver
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.reset(Configuration.java:322) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:261) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:265) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.<clinit>(Ejb3Configuration.java:150) ~[hibernate-entitymanager.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:71) ~[hibernate-entitymanager.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:257) ~[spring-orm.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310) ~[spring-orm.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
2013-10-02 13:15:30,410 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Final attempt in Phase: Deployment Processing Phase failed for transaction: tcm:0-399-66560
2013-10-02 13:15:30,412 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Original stacktrace for transaction: tcm:0-399-66560
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at com.tridion.storage.deploy.PageHandler.deploy(PageHandler.java:58) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:90) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy.processPage(PageDeploy.java:145) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy.processItem(PageDeploy.java:118) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:83) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:87) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.process(SectionVisitor.java:60) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.Processor.process(Processor.java:109) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.workers.ProcessorWorker.doWork(ProcessorWorker.java:77) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.ProcessingPhase.execute(ProcessingPhase.java:72) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:186) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:97) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:61) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:82) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:175) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fatal error, unable to load the StorageManagerFactory
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.reloadInstance(StorageManagerFactory.java:91) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.<clinit>(StorageManagerFactory.java:56) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlserverEntityManagerFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/DTDEntityResolver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1093) ~[spring-context.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory.configureBundle(JPADAOFactory.java:66) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.configureStorage(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:91) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.configureStorage(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:65) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.configure(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:51) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.configuration.step.ConfigurationStepLoader.configure(ConfigurationStepLoader.java:47) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.configure(StorageManagerFactory.java:137) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.services.BaseService.<init>(BaseService.java:107) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.<init>(StorageManagerFactory.java:104) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.reloadInstance(StorageManagerFactory.java:84) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/DTDEntityResolver
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.reset(Configuration.java:322) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:261) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:265) ~[hibernate-core.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.<clinit>(Ejb3Configuration.java:150) ~[hibernate-entitymanager.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:71) ~[hibernate-entitymanager.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:257) ~[spring-orm.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310) ~[spring-orm.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
2013-10-02 13:15:30,414 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Unable to start processing deployment package with transactionId: tcm:0-399-66560
com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Phase: Deployment Processing Phase failed, null, null
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:197) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:97) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:61) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:82) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:175) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
```

The `cd_extension.log` is created but stays empty, which makes sense I guess, since it looks like the storage can't be done at all. But its unclear to me why exactly (I don't see any references to anything si4t in the stacktrace).

A few interesting things I found was that my Deployer seems to be using Java 1.6.0_26 while in my Solr Admin I see that it is using 1.7.0_25 23.25-b01 (but I don't see that as the direct cause).

Any idea where I messed up or what might be causing this?

### Update

I see the `hibernate.validator.jar` and `hibernate.annotations.jar` that come with SI4T are version 3.4.0 while SDL Tridion 2013 uses Hibernate 4.0.1, that seems to be an issue. But also I find that Hibernate 4 doesn't use `hibernate-annotations` anymore, so it looks like I'm using a complete wrong set of jars for SI4T.

### Update 2

Downloaded the jars from [SI4T search integration with Tridion 2013](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2280/si4t-search-integration-with-tridion-2013/2287#2317) and trying with those. Getting a new error now, but I also see messages appearing in the `cd_extensions.log` so I'm getting closer.

> StorageManagerFactory - Fatal error, unable to load the StorageManagerFactory 
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrServerException

### Update 3

Okay that error is because I was missing the Solr jars, after adding those I see the following in the `cd_extension.log`:

> FSSearchDAOFactory - Could not load SearchIndexer. Check your configuration.

Have added an answer with the steps required to get here and will dive further, any help is still appreciated.

Comment: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2280/si4t-search-integration-with-tridion-2013/2287#2317 contains a link to download a working config/lib for 2013

Comment: Bart, if you are using the latest version of SI4T on 2013, you might find a few more issues: I would recommend to double check once you have it running:
1. Index update when Unpublishing
2. If you create a dedicated "storage" like solrFilesystem or solrDatabase, you might see that the "default" ones also kick in, we believe there's some kind of singleton implementation. I believe Rai is lookint at that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root problem was that, apart from configuration, all correct Java libraries had been placed in your Deployer's /lib directory.

Tridion 2011 and Tridion 2013 use quite a different set of java libraries for Content Delivery. Additionally, since Apache Solr moved on to version 4.4.0 and most people will start using this version, I have updated SI4T for use with both Tridion and Solr versions. You can find all this on [GitHub](https://github.com/SI4T/Solr).

**If you use Tridion 2011 and Solr < 4.4.0, you can find the proper jar files list here:**

- [Tridion 2011 and Solr < 4.4.0 libs](https://github.com/SI4T/Solr/tree/Tridion-2011/lib)

**If you use Tridion 2013 and Solr 4.4.0, you can find the proper jar files list here:**

- [Tridion 2013 and Solr 4.4.0 libs](https://github.com/SI4T/Solr/tree/master/lib)

More information can be found in the [updated Wiki page](https://github.com/SI4T/Solr/wiki/SI4T-Solr-Configuration-101).

Answer (score 3):

I have an instance of 2013 with the latest version of SOLR and this are my jars:

```
        62,983 activation.jar
       445,288 antlr.jar
         4,467 aopalliance.jar
        95,536 apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar
       304,810 apache-mime4j-dom-0.7.2.jar
        16,642 apache-solr-analysis-extras-4.0.0.jar
        29,814 apache-solr-cell-4.0.0.jar
        50,438 apache-solr-clustering-4.0.0.jar
     1,898,799 apache-solr-core-4.0.0.jar
       214,414 apache-solr-dataimporthandler-4.0.0.jar
        31,055 apache-solr-dataimporthandler-extras-4.0.0.jar
       766,430 apache-solr-langid-4.0.0.jar
       371,816 apache-solr-solrj-4.0.0.jar
       138,236 apache-solr-test-framework-4.0.0.jar
        38,850 apache-solr-uima-4.0.0.jar
        22,251 apache-solr-velocity-4.0.0.jar
        43,033 asm-3.1.jar
       229,116 bcmail-jdk15-1.45.jar
     1,663,318 bcprov-jdk15-1.45.jar
        92,027 boilerpipe-1.1.0.jar
       266,533 cd_broker.jar
        70,929 cd_cache.jar
       283,477 cd_core.jar
       572,834 cd_datalayer.jar
       152,057 cd_deployer.jar
        30,369 cd_linking.jar
       231,307 cd_model.jar
       104,895 cd_tcdl.jar
       135,340 cd_undo.jar
        15,834 cd_wrapper.jar
        41,123 commons-cli-1.2.jar
       575,389 commons-collections.jar
       241,367 commons-compress-1.4.1.jar
       160,519 commons-dbcp.jar
        96,203 commons-pool.jar
       313,898 dom4j-1.6.1.jar
       313,898 dom4j.jar
        38,643 easylicense.jar
       185,566 fontbox-1.7.0.jar
        28,804 geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar
       934,783 guava-r05.jar
        81,271 hibernate-commons-annotations.jar
     4,253,629 hibernate-core.jar
       475,305 hibernate-entitymanager.jar
       102,661 hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.jar
       352,585 httpclient-4.1.3.jar
       181,410 httpcore-4.1.4.jar
        26,938 httpmime-4.1.3.jar
     7,407,144 icu4j-49.1.jar
     7,286,075 icu4j-4_8_1_1.jar
       521,237 isoparser-1.0-RC-1.jar
       648,253 javassist.jar
        89,967 jaxb-api.jar
       867,801 jaxb-impl.jar
        60,768 jboss-logging.jar
        11,209 jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec.jar
        17,308 jcl-over-slf4j.jar
        19,146 jdbcpool.jar
       153,253 jdom-1.0.jar
        51,088 jempbox-1.7.0.jar
       292,772 jsoup-1.6.2.jar
        46,367 jsr311-api.jar
        15,071 jta.jar
       220,813 juniversalchardet-1.0.3.jar
        20,639 log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.4.jar
       246,709 logback-classic.jar
       327,911 logback-core.jar
     1,527,069 lucene-analyzers-common-4.0.0.jar
     4,553,567 lucene-analyzers-kuromoji-4.0.0.jar
        22,891 lucene-analyzers-phonetic-4.0.0.jar
     2,038,850 lucene-core-4.0.0.jar
       164,799 lucene-grouping-4.0.0.jar
        99,553 lucene-highlighter-4.0.0.jar
        37,148 lucene-memory-4.0.0.jar
        50,820 lucene-misc-4.0.0.jar
       194,653 lucene-queries-4.0.0.jar
       384,953 lucene-queryparser-4.0.0.jar
        67,642 lucene-spatial-4.0.0.jar
       120,182 lucene-suggest-4.0.0.jar
        90,929 metadata-extractor-2.4.0-beta-1.jar
     4,326,608 netcdf-4.2-min.jar
     3,908,404 pdfbox-1.7.0.jar
        52,150 persistence-api.jar
     1,820,323 poi-3.8.jar
       933,010 poi-ooxml-3.8.jar
     4,706,775 poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8.jar
     1,186,887 poi-scratchpad-3.8.jar
       208,025 rome-0.9.jar
       278,281 serializer.jar
        42,417 si4t-solr.jar
        86,820 si4t.jar
        25,962 slf4j-api.jar
       331,474 spring-aop.jar
        53,079 spring-asm.jar
       589,253 spring-beans.jar
       106,819 spring-context-support.jar
       829,601 spring-context.jar
       442,400 spring-core.jar
       176,283 spring-expression.jar
       401,762 spring-jdbc.jar
       378,235 spring-orm.jar
       246,036 spring-tx.jar
       584,207 sqljdbc4.jar
        23,346 stax-api.jar
        90,722 tagsoup-1.2.1.jar
       463,945 tika-core-1.2.jar
       482,074 tika-parsers-1.2.jar
       421,339 velocity-1.6.4.jar
       346,580 velocity-tools-2.0.jar
        47,478 vorbis-java-core-0.1.jar
        14,752 vorbis-java-tika-0.1.jar
       520,969 wstx-asl-3.2.7.jar
     3,176,148 xalan.jar
     1,229,125 xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
       109,318 xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
     2,666,695 xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
        94,672 xz-1.0.jar
       608,239 zookeeper-3.3.6.jar
```

My deployer is a dedicated deployer for search and my cd_stoage_conf.xml looks like:

[cd_storage_conf.xml](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8iGL-gOuRyvcXNIS3VtdWl1RFE/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Will and Jaime, I got a few steps further. Indeed the answer was basically given [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2280/si4t-search-integration-with-tridion-2013/2287#2317) by Mohan; after following the steps described in the wiki, for SDL Tridion 2013 you need to remove some jars:

1. Remove `ejb3-persistence.jar` (because `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.jar` is used in 2013)
2. Remove `hibernate-annotations.jar` (it is included in the latest hibernate-core)
3. Remove `hibernate-valitor.jar`

After that I found that I needed to add all the required Solr jars (since I'm using Solr 4.4.0 I couldn't use those from Mohan's answer) and after that Deployment started working.

The `FSSearchDAOFactory` still threw an error:

> Could not load SearchIndexer. Check your configuration.

That error is indeed related to my config, I was using the default [`SearchDAOBundle.xml`](https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/blob/master/storage-extensions/conf/SearchDAOBundle.xml), but only added an `<Indexer>` element to my "filesystem" storage (since I'm not planning on indexing anything which goes into my database, I needed to remove the "persistence" storage bundle from `SearchDAOBundle.xml` and only keep the "filesystem" one).

Special thanks also to Raimond for helping me debug it all, as he mentioned he'll be releasing a new build for Solr 4.4.0 in combination with SDL Tridion 2013 soon.

Comment: Have you tried my list of jars?

Comment: Yes, they are the same as Mohan mentions in his answer basically, so it looks like my jar problem is solved for now.

Comment: Can you put your configuration here? if it doesn't find your SearchIndexer that's either you are missing the jar containing the search indexer or you have a typo (like package name) in your config file :)

Comment: Good to hear its fixed. In the coming days I will release a fully compatible 2013 version of SI4T, which is also compatible with Apache Solr 4.4.0 (which also has some changes).

Comment: @JaimeSantosAlcón which config? I have a feeling the error is in my Solr now, but unsure what configs I need to change in there. My pages are deployed and the INDEX-DATA-START is removed from there, so it looks like SI4T is picking it up correctly.

Comment: @BartKoopman your cd_storage_conf.xml. The fact that the index data is removed, means that the extension is working. The fact that it can't load the actual indexer jar, means that either configuration is wrong, or that the si4t-solr.jar is not present in your Deployer's /lib directory

Comment: I would say it is your solr setup. Can you check the index fields (schema.xml) match the fields you have in you INDEX-DATA?

Comment: I don't think so - as the last exception is thrown when the Factory can't load an instance of the search indexer - so this is all before any thing is even posted to the solr instance.