# Publishing fails with SI4T

Tags: si4t

I have set up SI4T with a custom SearchIndexer. The publishing now fails with this message `Could not load SearchIndexer. Check your configuration.`. What does this really mean, which configuration and what could be wrong in the config?

```
2015-04-24 13:07:45,042 INFO  JPASearchDAOFactory - Start committing transaction: tcm:0-1113-66560
2015-04-24 13:07:45,058 INFO  SearchIndexProcessor - Triggering Indexing for transaction: tcm:0-1113-66560
2015-04-24 13:07:45,058 ERROR JPASearchDAOFactory - Could not load SearchIndexer. Check your configuration.
2015-04-24 13:07:45,058 ERROR JPASearchDAOFactory - com.tridion.storage.si4t.SearchIndexProcessor - 262 : triggerIndexing
    com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory - 189 : commitTransaction
    com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory - 354 : commitTransaction
    com.tridion.deployer.phases.AbstractStorageStep - 32 : commitTransaction
    com.tridion.deployer.phases.CommitPhase - 77 : execute
    com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor - 198 : runMainExecutePhase
    com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor - 100 : doExecute
    com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor - 64 : execute
    com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager - 82 : handleDeployPackage
    com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1 - 180 : run
    java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter - -1 : call
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask - -1 : run
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor - -1 : runWorker
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker - -1 : run
    java.lang.Thread - -1 : run
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message `Could not load SearchIndexer. Check your configuration.` is thrown by the SI4T core (as in opposed to the Solr or other SearchIndexer implementation).

It means that there is no SearchIndexer configured in the Tridion storage configuration in `cd_storage_conf.xml` in the Content Delivery deployer application. So, SI4T is configured but on one of the `<Storage>` configurations the SI4T `<Indexer>` configuration is not set.

Check the `cd_storage_conf.xml` and check all the `<Storage>` nodes. You need an `<Indexer>` config in every `<Storage>` node (think of both database and filesystem storage) like so. See the [SI4T Solr Configuration 101](https://github.com/SI4T/Solr/wiki/SI4T-Solr-Configuration-101) for more info.

```
<Storage 
    Type="persistence" Id="defaultdb" dialect="MSSQL" 
    Class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory">
    <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
    <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
        <Property Name="serverName" Value="[SERVERNAME]" />
        <Property Name="portNumber" Value="[DBPORT]" />
        <Property Name="databaseName" Value="[DBNAME]" />
        <Property Name="user" Value="[DBBROKERUSERNAME]" />
        <Property Name="password" Value="[DBBROKERPASSWORD]" />
    </DataSource>
    <Indexer 
        Class="org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer" 
        DefaultCoreUrl="http://localhost:8080/solr/staging" 
        Mode="http" 
        DocExtensions="pdf,docx,doc,xls,xlsx,pptx,ppt">
        <Urls>
            <!-- SI4T: 
                    The Value attribute is the complete URL to a Solr Core
                    The Id attribute denotes a unique Tridion Publication Id
            -->
            <Url Value="http://localhost:8080/solr/staging_pub5" Id="5" />
            <Url Value="http://localhost:8080/solr/staging" Id="8" />
            <Url Value="http://localhost:8080/solr/staging" Id="12" />
        </Urls>
    </Indexer>
</Storage>

<Storage Type="filesystem" 
        Class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.FSSearchDAOFactory" 
        Id="defaultFile" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
    <Root Path="[STORAGE_PATH]" />
    <Indexer 
        Class="org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer" 
        Mode="http" 
        DefaultCoreUrl="http://localhost:8080/solr/staging" 
        DocExtensions="pdf,docx,doc,xls,xlsx,pptx,ppt">
        <Urls>
            <!-- <Url Value="http://localhost:8080/solr/staging" Id="5" />-->
            <Url Value="http://localhost:8080/solr/staging" Id="8" />
            <Url Value="http://localhost:8080/solr/staging" Id="12" />
        </Urls>
    </Indexer>
</Storage>
```

In our case I did put an Indexer configuration on the database storage, but I forgot to update filesystem storage.

[Bart mentioned](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/3012/88) that you can also fix this error by omitting certain storage types in `SearchDAOBundle.xml` if you do not need to index everything.